# Query returning duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PrintQuickBill](@BillNo int)
AS
SELECT      A.BillNo, 
            A.BillDate, 
            A.CustomerName, 
            A.Address, 
            A.CustomerId, 
            A.BillLaborAmt, 
            A.BillPartAmt, 
            A.ServTaxAmt, 
            A.VatAmt,
            A.BillNetAmt,
FROM        dbo.tblQuickBillMain A
INNER JOIN  [dbo].tblQuickBillLabor L
        ON  A.BillNo = L.BillNo
INNER JOIN  [dbo].tblQuickBillParts P
        ON  A.BillNo = P.BillNo
CROSS JOIN  dbo.CompanyInfo
WHERE       A.BillNo=@BillNo
ORDER BY    CustomerName
```

This `SELECT` statement returns the same result multiple times. If I have 1 record the result shows it 3 times. If I pass `@BillNo=1` to the procedure, it should return only ***one row*** but it returns 3 rows, which are identical.

Comment: Without looking at the data it is hard to tell. I guess it is due to `CROSS JOIN` at the end

Comment: This happens when `tblQuickBillLabor.BillNo` has duplicates, or when `tblQuickBillParts.BillNo` has duplicates, or when `CompanyInfo` has more than one record. Because you don't show any of the data from those tables in the SELECT list, you don't see the difference between results which now look the same.

Comment: Like @trincot, I'll mention that if `CompanyInfo` contains anything more than a singleton row, the result set will be duplicated that many times.  Also if it contains NO rows, then neither will the result set.  Are you actually returning any columns from `CompanyInfo` or using its data in some part of the join or where predicate this abbreviated example omits?  If not, then why is it even in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duplicates result from one of the following three situations (or a combination of them):

- When ***CompanyInfo*** has more than one record (like 3 records).
- When ***tblQuickBillLabor.BillNo*** has duplicates;
- When ***tblQuickBillParts.BillNo*** has duplicates;

You don't see the difference between some results because you don't show any of the data from those other tables in the `SELECT` list. If you would include columns from the other tables in your `SELECT` list as well, you would notice that those columns would have different values in the results where the first bunch of columns would have duplicates.

But as you do not use values from the table ***CompanyInfo*** at all in your query, you should any way remove the `CROSS JOIN CompanyInfo` part of your query: it serves no purpose unless you actually include columns from that table in your `SELECT` list. Removing this might already completely solve your problem.

However, the table name ***tblQuickBillParts*** suggests strongly that you will have multiple records for the same ***BillNo*** in that table, otherwise you would not call it ***Parts*** in plural. The same might be true for the table ***tblQuickBillLabor***.

To deal with these potential problems, caused by the join with ***tblQuickBillLabor.BillNo*** and ***tblQuickBillParts.BillNo***, see the following solutions:

### Solution A: Do not join tables at all

As you are only selecting values from *tblQuickBillMain*, you might eventually not need to join the other tables at all, and just write:

```
SELECT   BillNo, 
         BillDate, 
         CustomerName, 
         Address, 
         CustomerId, 
         BillLaborAmt, 
         BillPartAmt, 
         ServTaxAmt, 
         VatAmt,
         BillNetAmt,
FROM     dbo.tblQuickBillMain
WHERE    BillNo=@BillNo
ORDER BY CustomerName
```

This way you will not get duplicates, but you will also get records for which there is no corresponding record in ***tblQuickBillLabor.BillNo*** or ***tblQuickBillParts.BillNo***. If that match is a requirement, then check the next solution.

### Solution B: Replace joins with sub-queries

If the reason for the joins with ***tblQuickBillLabor.BillNo*** and ***tblQuickBillParts.BillNo*** is that you want to be sure there is at least one matching record in those tables, then use a `WHERE` condition instead in the form of `BillNo IN (sub query)`:

```
SELECT   BillNo, 
         BillDate, 
         CustomerName, 
         Address, 
         CustomerId, 
         BillLaborAmt, 
         BillPartAmt, 
         ServTaxAmt, 
         VatAmt,
         BillNetAmt,
FROM     dbo.tblQuickBillMain
WHERE    BillNo=@BillNo
AND      BillNo IN (SELECT BillNo FROM [dbo].tblQuickBillLabor)
AND      BillNo IN (SELECT BillNo FROM [dbo].tblQuickBillParts)
ORDER BY CustomerName
```

Note that with this SQL statement you do not need to alias your tables with ***A***, ***P***, ***L*** as there is no ambiguity.

### Solution C: The Bad `SELECT DISTINCT`

A simple, but lazy and not advisable way to remove duplicates from the result set is to [add the word `DISTINCT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) right after the word `SELECT`.

With this *"solution"* you don't really get to the source of the problem; you just ignore it and ask for a non-duplicate result set. So, I would really suggest to go for solution A or B, whichever fits best to your requirements.

Comment: Pity **Solution 2** isn't given top place. Although you rightly mention that select distinct just disguises the underlying problem, already too many folks use that band aid.

Comment: @Used_By_Already, you are absolutely right. I updated the priority order and put the DISTINCT one in the last position, with some more explicit text giving it a bad score.

Comment: thanks for solutions, I will try and revert you soon, as all of mention that there is no Data then I will post the data and complete query as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a cross join to table CompanyInfo. And it is returning three rows, because the table in cross join (CompanyInfo) has three rows. You are not using any column from CompanyInfo, so I don't think that there is any need of that cross join.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. It is important to write quality answers. I corrected several spelling mistakes for you, and added missing spaces, commas and capitals.